# Есть одна задача

Tags: python, список, словарь

https://stepik.org/lesson/3363/step/2?unit=1135 вот задача.

вот мой код:

```
dictionary = {}
letters = []
numbers = []
numersof = ()
l = ''
r = ''
with open('dataset_3363_2.txt') as inf:
    string = inf.readline()
    for i in string:
        if i.isalpha():
            letters += i
    for i in string:
        if i.isdigit():
            l += str(i)
        elif i.isalpha():
            l += str(' ')
    for i in l.split():
        numbers.append(i)
dictionary = dict(zip(letters, numbers))
for i in dictionary:
    r += i * int(dictionary[i])
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(r)
```

Мне не нужны гениальные решения в три строки, помогите пожалуйста разобраться со своим кодом.
ИМХО: Мой код не проходит проверку из-за того, что после dict(zip(letters, numbers), у полученного ключи и значения не совпадают со списками numbers и letters.

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вашего кода огромный недостаток в том, что он просто не способен работать с повторяющимися буквами, например `a3b1a2`, потому что словарь хранит уникальные ключи

поэтому вопрос - зачем вам вообще словарь - формируйте строку по ходу анализа входной строки

```
string = "a3b1a2"
res = ''

str_count = ''
letter = ''

for i in string:
    if i.isdigit():
        str_count += i
    elif i.isalpha():
        res += int(str_count) * letter if letter != '' else ''
        str_count = ''
        letter = i

res += int(str_count) * letter if letter != '' else ''

print(res)
```